# Can servers be synchronised to share the same configurations?

Tags: centos, maintenance

I have three VPS' running on separate hosts. They've had CentOS 5 installed on them at various points and I assume all run with slight variations of Webmin, PHP, MySQL etc.

I've started to notice slight differences in how each server does tasks that are the same (eg, a Wordpress plugin might work on one VPS, but not on another - just as a general example).

I'm still quite new to Linux and server admin, so clearly there's a lot to learn about housekeeping etc, but I'm quite happy that I've managed to get the servers up and running and serving pages!

What I'm wondering, though, is whether or not there's an easier way of managing those three separate servers, so that they all run an identical configuration. Is it possible to synchronise/ mirror the configuration of one server across several others and if so, how?

I'm running CentOS 5 with Webmin and Virtualmin, as mail and web servers.

Comment: Have a look at the question about [linux bulk remote administration](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40401/linux-bulk-remote-administration)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Configuration management softwares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_configuration_management_software), have been designed to solve this exact problem.

You could start with puppet or chef and see what suits your purpose.